# From long to wide form without id.var?

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have some data in long form that looks like this:

```
dat1 = data.frame(
  id = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=4),
  value = 1:8
)
```

In table form:

```
id   value
A    1
A    2
A    3
A    4
B    5
B    6
B    7
B    8
```

And I want it to be in short form and look like this:

```
dat1 = data.frame(A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
```

In table form:

```
A  B
1  5
2  6
3  7
4  8
```

Now I could solve this by looping with `cbind()` and stuff, but I want to use some kind of reshape/melt function as these are the best way to do this kind of thing I think.

However, from spending >30 minutes trying to get `melt()` and `reshape()` to work, reading answers on SO, it seems that these functions requires the `id.var` to be set. Now, it is plainly redundant for this kind of thing, so how do I do what I want to do without having to resort to some kind of looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has been answered before. Anyway, `unstack` is convenient in this particular case with equal group size:

```
unstack(dat1, form = value ~ id)
#   A B
# 1 1 5
# 2 2 6
# 3 3 7
# 4 4 8
```

Comment: I could not find it. All the answers and guides I found assumed that one would be using an id.var. I just have stacked data with no id.var. Of course, I could give them an appropriate id.var e.g. `rownames(dat1) = rep(1:4,2)`, but that defeats the purpose of doing it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Solution below works when there are different numbers of As and Bs. For equal counts, `unstack` works great and with less code ([Henrik's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712/henrik) answer).

```
# create more general data (unbalanced 'id')
each <- c(4,2,3)
dat1 = data.frame(
    id = unlist(mapply(rep, x = LETTERS[1:length(each)], each = each)),
    value = 1:sum(each),
    row.names = 1:sum(each) # to reproduce original row.names
)

tab <- table(dat1$id)
dat1$timevar <- unlist(sapply(tab, seq))
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat1, timevar ~ id )[-1]
```

initial data:

```
id value
1  A     1
2  A     2
3  A     3
4  A     4
5  B     5
6  B     6
7  C     7
8  C     8
9  C     9
```

result:

```
  A  B  C
1 1  5  7
2 2  6  8
3 3 NA  9
4 4 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R approach to consider. It uses the `lengths` function, which I believe was introduced in R 3.2.

```
x <- split(dat1$value, dat1$id)
as.data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) `length<-`(y, max(lengths(x)))))
#   A  B  C
# 1 1  5  7
# 2 2  6  8
# 3 3 NA  9
# 4 4 NA NA
```