# How to extract+transpose values against unique identifiers in

Tags: r

I have an excel table with contents as shown in current... would like to get to a transposed table with values listed against each unique identifier as shown in the image. Would appreciate any input. I have a table with about 4k entries that I want to sift through with this script.

[image: image.png]

```
library(readxl)
samplesheet \<- read_excel("path/to/filenames.xlsx")

samplesheet2=samplesheet\[,c('Data','Description')\]

data_uniq=unique(samplesheet2$Description)

summary=c()

for (i in data_uniq){
fastq=samplesheet\[which(samplesheet$Description == i),'Data'\]
if(length (Data) \< 4){
T2=c(fastq, '')
}
n_row=c(i,T2)
summary1=rbind(summary1,n_row)
}

summary2=as.data.frame(summary1)
```

my current output looks like this:

[image: image.png]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Note that data.frames in R are rectangular ; that is, all rows must have the same number of columns. Your picture makes it looks like you have different columns per row. What are you going to do with this data after you have transformed it?

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272

Comment: ^yes, it's mostly a dupe of those, the difference being this is one of those reshape questions where it helps to first make an id number for each row within the identifier, which can then be used to define the reshaped columns. I'm gonna look for a closer match.

Comment: @JonSpring agreed, I just provided that ... it's hard to close as a dupe when the dupes are either one or the other ... I might record this as "add id then pivot" as a meta of the two concepts.

Comment: here's an old one, not ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301778/r-reshape-data-long-to-wide-with-unknown-number-of-columns

Comment: agreed, not a fan of answers using `ddply` these days :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417536/from-long-to-wide-form-without-id-var

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560437/long-to-wide-with-no-unique-key

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: @r2evans so many dupes, I can keep going; you actually posted an answer to the 2nd one (although that's not a perfect dupe). p.s. I burnt my CV for no mcve, please use your mjolnir if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

This needs first a grouping operation (to assign row-within-group) and then a pivot.

Sample data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(X1=as.character(13:19), X2=c(rep("PA-80-A",2), rep("BA-64-B", 5)))
```

## base R and reshape2

```r
dat$rn <- with(dat, ave(X1, X2, FUN = seq_along))
reshape2::dcast(X2 ~ rn, data = dat, value.var = "X1")
#        X2  1  2    3    4    5
# 1 BA-64-B 15 16   17   18   19
# 2 PA-80-A 13 14 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

## dplyr+tidyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat |>
  mutate(.by = X2, rn = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = X2, names_from = rn, values_from = X1)
# # A tibble: 2 × 6
#   X2      `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`  
#   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 PA-80-A 13    14    NA    NA    NA   
# 2 BA-64-B 15    16    17    18    19
```

---

Some references:

- Summarize by group

  - [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272)
  - [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272)
  - [Apply several summary functions (sum, mean, etc.) on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272) (multiple functions)
- Reshape, long-to-wide

  - [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272)
  - [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272)

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you choose `reshape2::dcast()` instead of `base:reshape`, i.e. `reshape(dat, direction = "wide", idvar = "X2", timevar = "rn")
`? (+1) Side note: What das *AC downvoter* mean? Never read.

Comment: I tend to prefer `reshape2::` and `tidyr::pivot_*`, I think `base::reshape` is a bit more difficult to use. Especially for users "new" to reshaping data, I think `base::reshape` is a steep learning curve. ("AC" is a throwback to Slashdot days; I think my answer is correct, reproducible, and resolves the problem, I get frustrated when somebody ***anonymously*** downvotes with no criticisms or suggestions to improve what they believe to be low quality.)

Comment: @r2evans With a 5-digit Slashdot ID, I know you don't mean "AC" derogatorily, but given the context, and for someone who isn't familiar with that culture, it comes across a whole lot worse than I know you mean it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the candid feedback @NotTheDr01ds. I realize it comes across harshly, I'll delete it. (Are you a 5-digit ID holder at slashdot? I admit to being more of a lurker than a contributor there ...)

Comment: Yes, I have a 5 digit at Slashdot (vs. my 8 digit here on SO ...), so ... early days.  My usage has fallen off as well, though, and I don't think I've posted in ~5 years.

Comment: I'm middle of the 5-digits there ... that site seems to be extremely slow today, took me a while to verify @NotTheDr01ds